# WinError 126 while import lightgbm in python

Tags: python, lightgbm

I use [pip install lightgbm] and success, but couldn't import lightgbm. my python version is Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)|.
Can anyone point me to a possible solution? Thanks for your help.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-bd597743fb90>", line 1, in <module>
    import lightgbm

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .basic import Booster, Dataset

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 32, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 27, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] 找不到指定的模块。[couln't find the module]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install vc runtime in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For the people digging for proper fix for the above problem. Use the below method to fix the problem.

first run the python shell. (or type `python` in your command prompt window).
If you have already installed lightgbm (if you haven't, type `pip install lightgbm` in a new cmd window & continue to next step), type the following in python shell.

`import lightgbm`

It will throw an error saying
**vcomp140.dll missing**

Once you get this error, visit the following link.
[Click to download vcomp140.dll](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/vcomp140_dll.html) and download the **vcomp140.dll** file.

Once you have downloaded the zip/rar, open it and place the **vcomp140.dll** in your system32 folder.

Now reopen the command prompt window. Type `python` and hit enter.
type `import lightgbm`.
Now it should not throw any errors.